# Union of subextensions of an Extension field is still a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am currently reading Lang’s treatment of Galois theory in his algebra book. However,I am stuck on the proof of corollary 2.6 on page 232. It talks about the union of algebraic sub extensions of E over k. However, I do not see why this should be a field. I know that the set of algebraic elements in E over k is a field but why should this union be one also. Can someone care to explain?

Comment: The compositum $EF$ of two subfields is by definition a field, namely the smallest field containing $EF$.  So point $6.$ in the duplicate answers your question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Or when he means union of the algebraic extensions is he referring to the compositum of the family of algebraic extensions?

Comment: 6. says that E is the *compositum* of all its finitely generated subfields over k. A compositum is always a field by definition - the smallest field containing all the factors. By 3. this is the union.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you. So when Lang stated union he was referring to the compositum? If so, this compositum can be written as a union of finitely generated sub fields over k. But how do we know that these are algebraically closed over k? The compositim could include more elements than the ones in the algebraic sub extensions.